# python remove certain dynamic lines from txt file

Tags: python

I have a couple of txt files with the data line structure below:

File1

```
Header1, xx, yy
Redundant line 1
Redundant line 2
Redundant line 3
Header2, #012345 (random numbers)
data content (to the end of file)
```

File2

```
Header1, xx, yy
Redundant line 1
Redundant line 2
Redundant line 3
Redundant line 4
Header2, #67891 (random numbers)
data content (to the end of file)
```

File3

```
Header1, xx, yy
Redundant line 1
Redundant line 2
Header2, #54321 (random numbers)
data content (to the end of file)
```

**Expected Output:**

For each file, I'd like to remove those Redundant lines and only keep the lines of Header1, Header2, #zzzzz number and the following lines with data content to the end of file, and save to a new individual file thus each new file has the data structure below:

```
Header1, xx, yy
Header2, #zzzzz (keep random numbers from original file)
data content (to the end of file)
```

**My Code:**

My code is not applicable to each file with dynamic redundant lines, could someone help with  some advices, thank you!

```
with open('File1.txt') as old, open('new_file1.txt', 'w') as new:
    lines = old.readlines()
    new.writelines(lines[0:1]) #keep Header1
    new.writelines(lines[N:]) #keep Header2 and following data content to the end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the `N` variable with an initial value of `1`, and keep incrementing it by `1` until a line matches the regular expression `.*?,#\d+` *(for the second header)*:

```
import re
with open('File1.txt') as old, open('new_file1.txt', 'w') as new:
    lines = old.readlines()
    new.writelines(lines[:1]) #keep Header1
    N = 1
    while True:
        N += 1
        if re.match(".*?,#\d+", lines[N]):
            break
    new.writelines(lines[N:]) #keep Header2 and following data content to the end
```

Input file `File1.txt`:

```
Header1, xx, yy
Redundant line 1
Redundant line 2
Redundant line 3
Header2, #012345 (random numbers)
data content (to the end of file)
```

Output file `new_file1.txt`:

```
Header1, xx, yy
Header2, #012345 (random numbers)
data content (to the end of file)
```

Comment: Thank you @Ann Zen. The redundant lines in each of actual txt file are not identical. Each redundant line has different content. So, I probably wouldn't save the first redundant line to a variable for comparison in while loop. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @KelvinLo How can one tell if a line is a redundant line and not the second header?

Comment: Header1 and Header2 are fixed format and identical content across all files, so we can identify the lines in between Header1 and Header2 are all redundant.

Comment: thank you so much, it is very close. My actual Header2 format is like 'AAAA BBB,CCC,#8000022400' Could you help with the regex to fit my actual example please?

Comment: @KelvinLo Simply remove the space from the regular expression `.*?, #\d+`, making it `.*?,#\d+`.

Comment: Thank you @Ann Zen. It works perfectly!